# Is there a better way making horizontal scroll between different table views?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I need to implement the following feature:

I need to show a user list of many table views containing many cells each. One table view at a time. So user scrolls up and down within current table view and scroll left and right to go between different table views.

The way that I implemented it right now:

- I have a scroll view occupying full screen.
- Content size for this scroll view is three times wider then size of the screen.
- In this content I layout three different table views.
- Only second (middle one) table is displayed initially.
- When user scrolls right or left I catch the end of scrolling event and reposition content back to the middle view and reload all three table views.

Am I missing something? Is there way to optimize it?

Comment: What's the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a github liker for [SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView). Just to implement datasource to setup tableViews on. This is useful for me.

Comment: I don't think it supports infinite scrolling out-of-the box. You need to specify certain number of pages there.

Comment: in delegate `reloadData` may could make it be possible. And You can try use horizontal tableView instead of scrollview. CellForRow to load tableView, and end of scrolling to reset offset.